# How to call this generic function?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have tried many ways to call the `countGreaterThan()` function ([described here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)), but I am unable to get it to work. I understand I need to use `Integer` instances and not primitives. This is what I've tried:

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Integer[] myArray = {0,1,2,3,4};
    Integer myInt = new Integer(2);
    int result = countGreaterThan(myArray,myInt);
            System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

This is the interface Comparable.java

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
   public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

And this is the error I get -

> Bound mismatch: The generic method countGreatherThan(T[],T) of type
>   MainClass is not applicable for the arguments(Integer[],Integer). The
>   inferred type Integer is not a valid subsitute for the bounded
>   parameter >

Comment: What does _doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: You should definitely show us countGreaterThan method, or at least it's signature, so we know what type it returns (if any) and what it does in it's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to wonder if you've created your own Comparable.java interface and are using it. If so, you're seeing your error because Integer is not using your interface, but rather the one that is part of core Java. If so, get rid of your Comparable.java class, delete it, and just use the one that is part of core Java. No need to import as it is part of the java.lang package, a package whose classes are all automatically imported by default.

Comment: @user3745246: Sorry for annoying you to improve your question, but note that we could only figure this out after you did your improvents. Thanks for the improvements and you're welcome for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it appears like you are calling `countGreaterThan()`! What you aren't doing is printing the result, or saving the result.

```
countGreaterThan(myArray,myInt);
```

Should be

```
int result = countGreaterThan(myArray, myInt);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I actually ran the code. It's fine.

Comment: The method is in the link in the original post.

Comment: The real problem is that it doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, the one at the bottom of that link does.

Comment: I've tried to compile using your 2 lines of code but it didn't work either.  I still get this error http://gyazo.com/8d9cbba14b91d8758d670eecb16b65c3

Comment: There are 3 of my replies before this comment, including a screenshot, what should I add more ?

Comment: I edited 1st post, check it now and tell me if it's ok this time.

Comment: @user3745246: much better, thank you! 1+ up-vote. Vote to close retracted.

Comment: My bad. 1+ to your answer.